# UIcollectionview Update cell height

Tags: ios, swift4

Currently I am working on one dynamic layout of collection view.

On certain clicks inside collectionview cell (ex cell has UIbutton) the cell of that click button should increase height.

i have implemented the method of collectionviewflowlayoutdelegate 
SizeforItemAt:

When cell button click i am just reloading particular one indexpath
self.collectionview.reloadItems([indexpath])

It will call SizeforItemAt: but it is calling for all cell again. So due to this my collectionview jerking all cells as it’s sizes are updating.

So is there any way to update height for single cell only?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize{
    let width = collectionView.bounds.width
    let height = 0.0
    // for specific cell  height
    if indexPath.row == 1{
        height = 200.0 // chnage height for a specific cell
    }else{
        height = collectionView.bounds.height //actual height
    }
    return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
}
```

**Update**

I am not sure will it work or not when clicking on the button.

But you can change the height of a specific cell that is selected by implementing `didSelectItemAt` like the below.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    collectionView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)

    // to reload specific cell use below line. 
    //collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
}
```

You can Check if the `idexPath` in `sizeForItemAt` is selected or not. if it is selected then you can change the height otherwise return the original height. like the following.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    switch collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first {
    case .some(indexPath):
        let height = 200.0 // here you can change the height for selected cell.
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width,height: height) 
    default:
        let height = 200.0 // standard height
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: height)
    }
}
```

Comment: No bro you didn’t get my question. As i am increasing cell size as per content which i will get from api. And then after clicking on button, it should increase size only for one cell.  So the method SizeforItemAt should call for only one cell.

Comment: @Jaimish "So the method SizeforItemAt should call for only one cell" You are using the word "should" in a strange way. It is not up to _you_ how `sizeForItemAt` is called. Your job is to deal with it correctly when it _is_ called.

Comment: @JakirHossain what if when i reloadItems for some indexpath array. For which indexpath sizeforItemAt: will call ? Only those indexpath or for all again?

Answer (score 0):

Check for collection view cell dynamic height.

And do not hard code height for cell, instead make the components inside the cell define the height of the cell. In this way when tap on button pragmatically increase/decrease the size of some component inside that cell and you would get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

> So is there any way to update height for single cell only?

No. If `sizeForItemAt:` is implemented, it can and will be called for any cells the runtime wishes. It isn't up to you what cell this is. Your job is to return the correct value for whatever the cell in question is. If you don't want to change a cell's height, don't change it, but you can't stop the call from arriving.

However, I doubt that this has anything to do with your issue. It sounds like what you want is to update the height of this one cell is a smooth (animated) manner. That has nothing to do with what you asked.

Comment: Understood and agreed but i am calling reloadItems and pass particular indexpaths that I want to reload and update height, at that time why it calling sizeForItemAt: for all cells. It should just call for only those indexpath which are i passed to at reload time. Hope you got my point. :)

Comment: Again, what you are saying involves a strange use of "should". You might mean "I _wish_ it worked that way". But I am telling you it doesn't. All heights are recalculated even if just one cell is reloaded. That is just the fact. You can say "should" all you like: it won't change anything about reality.

Comment: sorry for should word, i actually facing issue of jurking when i am tapping some button on cell and updating height.  Exactly want expand collapse kind thing in collection view with proper scroll and smooth. Accepting the reality what collection view is giving

Comment: Yes, well, this is what we call an x-y question. Instead of asking how to update the height for just one cell, you should have asked how to update the height of a cell smoothly.